# Getting current element's width in AngularJS within ng-repeat via directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, width

[SEE WHOLE EXAMPLE IN PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/xKsvLpo2ow6TyMNxGcPF?p=preview)

No errors but my directive does not output correct width values (clientWidth).

Following situation:

That is my data, 3 items (excerpt app.js):

```
$scope.data = [
  "Account Information",
  "Contact Person",
  "T&C"
];
```

That is the view (excerpt index.html):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" class="box" get-width="">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

That's the directive (excerpt app.js):

```
.directive('getWidth',function(){
  return {
    link: function (scope, element){
        console.log("Current Element's Width",element[0].clientWidth);
    }
}
```

That's the stylesheet, the boxes have different widths and they are already correct rendered:

```
  .box {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
```

[image: Rendered Output]

And as you see, the width (clientWidth) of the first element is 155:

[image: Width of the first Elment]

But I am getting the output (3 times): Current Element's Width 79, I was expecting 3 correct width values.

What is my mistake ? Maybe it is a timing problem and the text in divs were not renderetd at the time of getting width via the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right it is a timing issue.  Inject angulars $timeout and you'll get the results your looking for.

```
.directive('getWidth',function($timeout){
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr){
        $timeout(function(){
          console.log("Current Element's Width",element[0].clientWidth);
        })
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8HEcCeV7K13b6cCGyKq?p=preview